# How to list last commands run in tmux's current session's panes?

Tags: tmux

I want to write a script with a name `tmux-gen-curr-session` which will produce a script that will open panes and run last commands of each panes in current session.

Is there a easy way to get last commands that are run in each panes of current session?

Comment: I don't know about getting the recent commands, but I've used Tmux Ressurect (https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) with success. That sounds like what you are trying to accomplish..?

Comment: I didn't try that out, but you seem to be correct, what I want to achieve is nearly this project, except for I need to get only current session and I need to resurrect the session in `/etc/rc.local`, not upon user interact.